# How to show hidden/hide folders/files for only "one specific drive"?

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to HIDE hidden folders/files in my second (Which is actually D:) drive and SHOW hidden folders/files in my primary (Which is C:) drive without installing third party software?

Answer (score 0):

## First way

Step 1: Open This PC.
Double-click This PC on the desktop to open it.
You can also open another folder such as Network, File Explorer, Recycle Bin, etc.

Step 2: Show the hidden files and folders in the View menu.
Click View, tap Show/hide in the menu, and check the small box before Hidden items in the sub-list.

## Second Way :Show hidden files and folders in the Folder Options.

Step 1: Open Folder Options.
Open This PC, click View and select Options.

Step 2: Show the hidden files and folders in the View settings.
In the Folder Options window, choose View, select Show hidden files, folders, and drives, and then click OK.

Comment: I want to hide hidden folders/files in my second (Which is actually D:) drive and show hidden folders/files in my primary (Which is C:) drive AT THE SAME TIME. I know I can show or hide hidden files/folders in Windows.

Comment: Click on your D: and click View at the top. There you will see show hidden folders check box. Uncheck it and Viola!

Comment: I KNOW I CAN SHOW or HIDE HIDDEN FILES IN WINDOWS. I ASK FOR CAN I DO THAT FOR ONLY A "SPECIFIC DRIVE"?

Comment: YES YOU CAN. :>

Comment: If I do check that "show / hidden folders" it does show or hidden folders for ALL DRIVES. I want to do this for ONE SPECIFIC FOLDER.